# C# Can i change (Visually) a dropdownlist AutoPostBack="true" from .cs?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, autopostback

i want to change a DropDown Selection (Visually at PageLoad) using code

-----------------------------[aspx]------------------------------------

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cbo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
<asp:ListItem Value="3">ALL</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1">YES</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">NO</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

-----------------------------[/aspx]------------------------------------

in my .cs file i want to do this

-----------------------------[cs]------------------------------------

```
(pageload)
cbo.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

-----------------------------[/cs]------------------------------------

It's not working

Comment: When you say its not working, what does it mean. You were expecting which element to be selected?

Comment: _if I can understand you..._ If you want establish the `ListItem` at posticion `1` just add the property "Selected" in your `ListItem`. Example: `<asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="true">YES</asp:ListItem>`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are setting the selected index of another drop down. I think it should be cbo.SelectedIndex = 1

Comment: sorry, I changed the dropdown name to create this post...i edited...thanks but the problem is something else

Comment: no...the id mistake was made here during the creating of the post

Comment: Are you setting the SelectedIndex somewhere else in code on the same page?